# Firebase Firestore Emulator throwing java out of memory exception

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I'm having some serious issues understanding why the emulator won't import the exported firestore data I am feeding it. It keeps throwing a memory error. **Any help/ideas?**

These are the logs given by firestore-debug.log when trying to run command:
firebase emulators:start --import=./production_data_export

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.LevelDBLogReaderChannel.readRecord(LevelDBLogReaderChannel.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.LevelDBLogReaderChannel.readProtoMessage(LevelDBLogReaderChannel.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.ExportImportUtil.parseEntityProtoFile(ExportImportUtil.java:194)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.ExportImportUtil.fetchEntities(ExportImportUtil.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.CloudFirestore.main(CloudFirestore.java:90)
```

[folder structure of production_data_export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHRcz.png)

code for firebase-export-metadata.json

```
{
  "version": "10.2.0",
  "firestore": {
    "version": "1.13.1",
    "path": "",
    "metadata_file": "mock-db.overall_export_metadata"
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report that belong on the Firebase CLI GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to import a huge dataset, then you can try tweaking the memory size using `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"` (this sets it up for 4GB I think - not sure tho.... so you can increase or reduce based on what your machine is capable of). if you are on a linux or mac machine. I think for windows it is `set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"`

Got the idea from the official issues ticket: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4336#issuecomment-1075439749